# Bad results with cloth simulation - sewing

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am trying to create various clothes in blender by using cloth simulation with sewing, but I am getting quite poor results. In the image below I tried to create a balaclava but it always comes out really wrinkled, with gaps and clips through the base mesh in places.

I tried adjusting various options such as increasing and decreasing subdivision of the balaclava mesh, or increasing the simulation quality steps, but the result never looks good for some reason.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: 1) the gaps are normal (not their size but their existence). You can minimize their size with tweaking the settings and mesh topology. But if you want to get rid of them completely, you need to merge the mesh parts manually or with a script. 2) The more vertices a mesh has, the more wrinkles you can get. But it also increases the chance for unwanted behavior. If it ripples and "crawls", then it is usually a problem with the collision detection. It's a good idea to start with a low-poly mesh.

Comment: 3) It looks like you had a low-poly mesh and then applied a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. This is not ideal because the modifier does not add any needed "threads" (=the edges between the mesh parts) and instead subdivides the existing "threads". The missing "threads" create these large holes. 4) It also looks like your mesh is too small to fit the head. When sewing, the flat mesh needs to be much larger as it is wrapped around a 3D object. If it's too small, you will end up with large gaps because there is not enough mesh. The mesh can be stretched, but that's limited.

Comment: Here is a quick example, where I indeed forgot a few threads. This results in a gap/hole at the nose: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfNh1.jpg - [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRqwX.jpg